# algebraic derivation involving integration , expectation, and max function

Tags: definite-integrals, expectation

please help me prove this:

[image]

$K,R_0$ and $L_0$ are constants, $R$ is a random variable   , + superscript indicates $max(.,0)$
and $R_0$=E(R)

note: this comes from me trying to understand the maths of getting from equation 3.2 to 3.4a in the following paper: www.javaquant.net/papers/ConvexityConundrum.pdf

Comment: this is the 1st time i have done latex - i did it using a GUI at http://atomurl.net/math/  .  i dont know how to get the equation to appear without the link unfortunately!

Comment: Hint: This is a *pointwise* identity, that is, getting rid of the irrelevant factor $L_0$, for every real numbers $(k,r_0,r)$, one has $$(k-r_0)(r-k)^++2\int_k^\infty (r-x)^+dx=(r-r_0)(r-k)^+.$$ The proof is direct, treating $r<k$ and $r>k$ separately. (Unrelated: $k$ in the LHS of the identity in your question should read $K$.)

Comment: thanks, i am starting to get the idea!  so 1) L0 was silly to include , 2) the expectation can be taken outside of the integral  (i am still not perfectly sure of the proof of this) , 3) the integration can be done as you described, treating the 2 cases of k above and below r seperately.  thanks very much!

Comment: now i think some more, i realised that expectation can be taken out of integral, because integration is just adding , and expectation operator is additive!, so i think that completes my question.....  thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $R-x$ is positive if $x < R$. If $x \geq R$, then $(R-x)^+$ is equal to 0.

Therefore the upper bound for the integral is $R$:

$\ldots+2\int_K^R L_0E\left( R-x\right) \ dx$

Comment: ok that makes sense :)  but still i need some more hints!

Comment: But not the second line. What is your problem now ?

Comment: so you have shown me that instead of the upper limit of infinity , it is in fact R.  but i still need more help in the proof

Comment: important note!:  i am pretty sure that also it is defined that E(R) = R0    i will add this above, i forgot this!

Comment: That it what I has shown. You´re welcome. Now it´s your turn to show something and you have to tell me where your problem is. I don´t think that the condition $E(R)=R_0$ is needed here.

Comment: is it allowed to take the expectation outside the integral?

Comment: Yes, this is allowed.

Comment: ok so i understand the 2nd term on the LHS simplifies as per:    \int_k^ \infty  E((R-x)^+)dx
=  E\int_k^ R (R-x)^+dx
= Expected value of the area under the triangle , where R>=K
= E(0.5*((R-K)^+)^2)    (sorry i still have trouble writing the latex!)       now, i'm not certain how to sum the 2 terms on the left

Comment: First of all you can drop the + sign. $L_0E\int_K^R (R-x) \ dx =L_0E(Rx-\frac{1}{2}x^2)$ with $K \leq x \leq R$